# Root being controlled by ARD

Tags: ldap, mac-osx-server, root, remote-desktop

I run an educational lab of 20 iMacs, all running Mac OS 10.7.5(11G63) with ARD version 3.6.2. My server and all of the iMacs run Lion. I seem to have crossed something and now my root user is being controlled with the same preferences I have setup for my LDap users. Somehow, ARD has taken control of the root user, most notably the System Preferences. Is there a way around this problem. I need root to have full permissions (like it should), while still controlling the individual users who log on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean your admin user not the root user right?  Make sure you are managing user preferences and not computer preferences.

Comment: I do mean the root user - as in "Root". That's the problem. I am managing user preferences in my workgroup manager, but the user preferences extend to root for some reason.